# Smoothly sliding up and down content when tab is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

[Jsfiddle - accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/JWfdx/12/)

HTML

```
          <div class="accordion">
            <div id="step-1">
             <a href="#step-1" class="tab">Step 1 - Information</a>
              <div class="content">
                <div style="background: yellow;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc iaculis, arcu aliquam tempor ultrices, est arcu vehicula eros, in iaculis mauris mauris ac orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus tempus velit libero, vel dapibus dui vulputate sollicitudin. Etiam cursus mauris magna, et condimentum mauris rutrum at. Nam lectus eros, accumsan nec ligula at, euismod fringilla lectus. Fusce ac egestas neque, nec accumsan arcu. Nam consequat sem et interdum rutrum. Nam adipiscing massa et congue dignissim. Morbi cursus libero urna, in mollis ligula dignissim ac. Suspendisse et lacinia nibh, at convallis nunc. Vestibulum ipsum nulla, tincidunt id tempus id, sollicitudin quis nunc. Suspendisse potenti.

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="step-2">
              <a href="#step-2">Step 2 - Select</a>
              <div class="content">
                <div style="background: green;">
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc iaculis, arcu aliquam tempor ultrices, est arcu vehicula eros, in iaculis mauris mauris ac orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus tempus velit libero, vel dapibus dui vulputate sollicitudin. Etiam cursus mauris magna, et condimentum mauris rutrum at. Nam lectus eros, accumsan nec ligula at, euismod fringilla lectus. Fusce ac egestas neque, nec accumsan arcu. Nam consequat sem et interdum rutrum. Nam adipiscing massa et congue dignissim. Morbi cursus libero urna, in mollis ligula dignissim ac. Suspendisse et lacinia nibh, at convallis nunc. Vestibulum ipsum nulla, tincidunt id tempus id, sollicitudin quis nunc. Suspendisse potenti.

                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .accordion .tab {
  border-top: 1px solid #5b5b5b;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
}

.accordion .tab:hover,
.accordion div:target .tab {
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

.accordion div .content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion div:target .content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion > div {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion > div:target {
  height: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
 $('.accordion .tab').on('click', function(event) {
        var parent_tab = $(this).parent();
        if (parent_tab.hasClass('active'))
            $(".accordion .tab div.content:visible").slideToggle("normal");
        else {
            $(".accordion .tab div.content:visible").slideToggle("normal");
            $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("normal");
        }
    });
```

The issue is that with css3, it does not behave as same as the website [fortheloveoflaundry.com](http://www.fortheloveoflaundry.com/)

So tried jquery to achieve the smooth sliding accordion - When tabs are clicked once or twice, the panel does not slide up or down smoothly. Think JQuery is not working right.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already used `slideToggle` to animate it, so you don't need any CSS transition as well as CSS code changing the `height` in the `:target` rule. So many CSS code in your demo can be removed (I just commented them out). Here is the updated script:

```
//hide the content intially
$('.accordion div .content').slideToggle(0);   
$('.accordion .tab').on('click', function(event) {
    var parent_tab = $(this).parent();
    if (parent_tab.hasClass('active')) return;                    
    $('.active div.content').slideToggle();
    $(this).next("div.content").slideToggle();              
    $('.accordion .active').removeClass('active');
    parent_tab.addClass('active');       
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JWfdx/16/)

**UPDATE**: If you want the ***collapsible*** feature like in the accordion widget in jQuery UI, you can try **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JWfdx/17/)** instead.

Comment: thanks. but when i click one tab, then content open. it worked fine but when i click same tab again, the content doesn't close?

Comment: thanks for demo. I added a few lines to test if it will display the first content. Not sure why it is not working? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JWfdx/19/)

Comment: @joe looks like you want this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JWfdx/20/ Also you should have described exactly what you wanted so that you would have the solution sooner.

Comment: thanks and sorry. would it work for h3 if i replace a href tag with h3? I am trying it out.

Comment: Update: it seems not to be working for a href tag and h3 on my local. don't know why it is not as same as jsfiddle. i m figuring it out.

Comment: @joe it should work with `h3` instead as long as you keep using the class `tab` for the `h3` tags, check this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JWfdx/22/ . Also the cursor hovering on the `h3` should be `pointer` (to indicate it's clickable).

Comment: thanks so much for the help. Interesting that I replaced a href tag with h3 without class tab and changed a bit in jquery - it didn't work too well. So without class, it wouldn't work.